# Interrupt service script on reboot

Tags: ubuntu, python, services

My knowledge in this field is limited, so please excuse my ignorance and stupidity.

I've used these two questions/solutions ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955604/start-a-python-script-at-boot-on-ubuntu) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025312/start-a-python-script-at-startup-automatically)) to create a `.service` that will run a python script when a linux OS computer restarts. The first time I tried this was on a AWS EC2 machine and I ended up screwing myself with how I set it up. I had to completely scrap my work and start over. Within my python script I had something that would reboot the computer, and naturally once on reboot, the `.service` would be triggered. So essentially I kept restarting my computer. Unfortunately I could not execute `sudo systemctl stop myscript.service` before the computer would restart. So I was locked out of my computer. Never made that mistake again....

Looking back at it now and to avoid accidently getting into that situation again, how might I stop that specific `.service` from running? Is there a way to access the command line before "fully" rebooting? Or would I need to fully reinstall ubuntu? I'm also interested in suggestions for how others would set up a system like this.

For simplicity sake this is what I had:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some kind of description
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart= /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/post/bin/python3.8 /home/ubuntu/myPythonScript.py


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
import os

os.system('reboot')
```

Comment: `systemctl disable myscript` will keep it from being executed on reboot.

Comment: where would I input that at though? If the system is constantly rebooting due to the script, how or where do I input that?

Comment: do you have the grub menu  on boot? If you do then I can provide a possible solution.

Comment: I do want the script to be executed, so I guess a better question is how do I interrupt it?

Comment: @Binx if your computer is constantly rebooting the possible solution is to execute bash at boot using the grub

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I am not familiar with `grub menu`, please give me time to better understand this before confirming.

Comment: @Binx when you boot your Linux sometimes this can show a menu to select the operating system or might be entries to boot with specific kernel. Example of grub menu: https://www.profesionalreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/GRUB-1280x720.png

Comment: You will need to boot into rescue mode. One possible link [here](https://www.tecmint.com/boot-ubuntu-in-rescue-mode/). You can then chroot into the system and change the service. No, you cannot interrupt the script during the boot process, you need to disable it.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon okay yes, I do believe I have GRUB

Comment: Thanks @doneal24 I'll want to set up a VM to test this out. Don't want to test on my computer :D

Comment: @Binx great! 
Then try using the link that doneal24 provided, it should work. The another possible solution is booting with bash using the same grub menu and removing the service.

Comment: Thanks @EdgarMagallon ! Appreciate the comments and help! Will post when I test this out.